# Am I taking a risk or responsibility?

Tags: professionalism, career-development, ethics, project-management

I am an associate developer in a team of 2 developers. We have been working on a very important government project lately.

My only co-worker (very experienced and much my senior) has informed me he is going to resign soon, but hasn't informed management yet.

The project we are doing can be risky or not, and it will have a huge impact on large number of people. The project is nearing completion but we have a 2 year support agreement and we are scheduled for 2 updates in 6 months. I have little-to-no knowledge of updating technology.

His resignation will have a huge impact on the project and create an opportunity for me. If i take this as a responsibility it can be be good for my professional life. There is no one who knows this system or current API's in my office.

Or if I take the risk and fail, I will be putting my career at risk. This will affect others too if I do not get it, the office will assign new senior developer. This could be a new learning opportunity for me as well, but i lose the chance to show myself in a senior role.

So this is a risk I should avoid or a responsibility I need to take?

Comment: The best opportunities sometimes come when you're "not ready" for them. That doesn't necessarily imply failure (nor does being fully qualified imply success). Your question can't really be answered, but I will say if your concerns go far beyond simply not being able to meet the deadline then it is probably a good idea to not actively pursue this opportunity. Every advancement requires _some_ risk and _some_ non-optimal choices, the level of risk you're willing to take depends only on you.

Comment: I think you are over-thinking. Give it time. Talk to your co-worker. Since your company cannot loose both of you, they would do everything to keep you happy. You can probably just ask for a new title with no new responsibilities :)

Comment: You're the one that's best placed to make this type of judgement call not us. If they care much about your opinions, that is. If they decide that you are the one that's best qualified to replace your soon to be departing colleague and that they DO need a replacement, they'll replace him with you without thinking twice about it. You may not be able to replace him 100% but if you are the one that best fits the requirements - well, that's the way the chips fall. And you'll have a few sleepless nights ahead of you. They don't care about your angst, they do care that they need you.

Comment: The other consideration is your actual skill level. Do you have the knowldge or can you get the knowledge in a failry short time  to take on a bigger role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *sure* you're next in line?

It's not uncommon for tech shops to start the hiring process for a more senior developer after someone submits their notice, so that they can keep their development schedule on track.

In spite of that, given that you're worried if you will succeed or fail, I'd advise that you hold off stepping into a bigger role, as I don't think you're quite ready for it yet. Your expertise in the system is an important asset, but if you want to step into a more leadership role, you have to have both the knowledge and the temperament to weather you through potential success and failures.

Comment: thanks for the input :) the thing is there is no line :) , only me for now , and this can be one of life time chance.  the resign developer and I have spend over a year developing\learning this.even a senior developer have a chance of failing.